# SQL Statement doesnt work after putting a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT     
   Event.Id, Event.Title, Event.StartDateTime, Event.DeadlineDate, 
   [File].ShortFileName, People.Initials
FROM         
   People 
INNER JOIN
   People2Event ON People.Id = People2Event.PeopleId 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   [File] 
INNER JOIN
   File2Event ON [File].Id = File2Event.FileId 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   Event ON File2Event.EventId = Event.Id ON People2Event.EventId = Event.Id
```

I have this statement it works print all record. Below doesn't work it's the same statement with a where function. Does anyone know how to fix?

```
SELECT     
   Event.Id, Event.Title, Event.StartDateTime, Event.DeadlineDate, 
   [File].ShortFileName, People.Initials
FROM         
   People 
INNER JOIN
   People2Event ON People.Id = People2Event.PeopleId 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   [File] 
INNER JOIN
   File2Event ON [File].Id = File2Event.FileId 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   Event ON File2Event.EventId = Event.Id ON People2Event.EventId = Event.Id
WHERE 
   Event.ID = 8888
```

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work?

Comment: are you sure there's an Event with ID 8888?

Comment: Yes there is an eventID 8888. DOesn't work it's empty.

Comment: Are you sure event.ID is an int?  SQL Server implicit conversion is good, but you could possibly get an unusual situation if you have the 8888 in Event.Id stored as something unusual.  What happens if you just run "select * from event where id = 8888"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT     Event.Id, Event.Title, Event.StartDateTime, Event.DeadlineDate, [File].ShortFileName, People.Initials
FROM         [File] INNER JOIN
                      File2Event ON [File].Id = File2Event.FileId INNER JOIN
                      People INNER JOIN
                      People2Event ON People.Id = People2Event.PeopleId INNER JOIN
                      Event ON People2Event.EventId = Event.Id ON File2Event.EventId = Event.Id
WHERE     (Event.Id = 8888)
```

This does the trick for some reason. Used query designer.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT**:

As AndriyM points out, since the condition that was in the `WHERE` clause was on the right side of the `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, moving to the `ON` would have no effect.  The OP posted a query that contained only `INNER JOIN` that he says solved the problem, so there must have been some other issue with his query.

---

If you add a filter in your `WHERE` clause for a table that is part of an `OUTER JOIN`, it will eliminate any `NULL` rows, effectively turning your `OUTER JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.

Instead of placing the condition in your `WHERE` clause, move it to your `ON`:

```
File2Event ON [File].Id = File2Event.FileId RIGHT OUTER JOIN
Event 
    ON File2Event.EventId = Event.Id 
    AND People2Event.EventId = Event.Id
    AND Event.ID = 8888
```

Also, a tip on style, I'd avoid using `RIGHT JOIN`, and instead re-write your query to use `LEFT JOIN`... this typically makes the logic easier to follow.

Comment: In a right outer join, the NULL rows, if any, are returned by the left side, and `Event` is the right side of the join. So your point, while basically a good one, is inapplicable here.

Comment: @AndriyM Good point, you're right... I guess the RIGHT OUTER JOINs broke my brain...

Answer (score 1):

This would properly return no rows if there is no Event.Id.

One possible source of confusion may be that you are using a "right outer join" when you bring in Event so you might possibly expect it to still show the rows from the other table even with the filter.

But that filter is in your where clause, so the query as a whole will only return rows that match the condition of the filter.  In this case meaning that you will only see rows where event.id is 8888 and nothing else.

If you want it to show the rows from the event table but only show the information from the other tables when the event.id is 8888 then you can put that as part of your join.  It is a bit unusual to use a constant instead of a value from another table as part of a join clause, but the Server will happily accept it and only join when that condition is meant.  When using inner joins this is hardly ever useful, but for outer joins it can help control when data from another table is brought in.  It would look like:

```
SELECT     Event.Id, Event.Title, Event.StartDateTime, Event.DeadlineDate, [File].ShortFileName, People.Initials
FROM         People INNER JOIN
                      People2Event ON People.Id = People2Event.PeopleId RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      [File] INNER JOIN
                      File2Event ON [File].Id = File2Event.FileId RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      Event ON File2Event.EventId = Event.Id 
                      ON People2Event.EventId = Event.Id
                          AND Event.ID = 8888
```

Comment: It's giving me everything in my event table. When I write your code. I am expecting only 1 output.

Comment: It is using a right outer join, so you should expect everything from the event table with that version. But it will only join in the others for Event.ID = 8888.  Incidentally, as @MichaelFredrickson pointed out left join's are more common and will generally be easier to understand than right joins.